# How to write the results of a batch file called in a Python script to a file

Tags: python, batch-file, subprocess

I have a Python script in which I have a directory of .bat files. I loop through them and run each one through command line, then save the *result* of the batch script to a file. So far I have this:

```
import subprocess

for _, _, files in os.walk(directory):
    for f in files:
        fullpath = directory + os.path.basename(f)
        params = [fullpath]
        result = subprocess.list2cmdline(params)
```

However, this sets the `result` variable to the path of the .bat file, when I need the result of running the code *in* the ,bat file. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you calling `list2cmdline`? This doesn't actually call the subprocess.

Use [`subprocess.check_output`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) instead:

```
import os

output = []

for _, _, files in os.walk(directory):
    for f in files:
        fullpath = os.path.join(directory, os.path.basename(f))
        output.append(subprocess.check_output([fullpath]))

print '\n'.join(output)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, one quick followup, if I only need the data from the file immediately after its file is accessed and I need *just* the data from that one file, would it make more sense for output to be declared inside the loop?

Comment: @thnkwthprtls Sure, just do `output = subprocess.check_output([fullpath])`, and then do something with `output`.

Answer (score 0):

To write result (output) of a command to a file, you could use `stdout` parameter:

```
import os
from glob import glob
from subprocess import check_call

for path in glob(os.path.join(directory, "*.bat")):
    name, _ = os.path.splitext(path)
    with open(name + ".result", "wb") as outfile:
        check_call(path, stdout=outfile)
```